# How can I customise an ISO image of Webconverger with a Linux shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, live-cd

I want to write a simple shell script that downloads the latest ISO image of Webconverger and changes the boot parameters of grub in `/boot/live.cfg`.

So this is what I have done so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
# 1. Download the ISO
wget https://build.webconverger.com/latest.iso

# 2. Mount the ISO and create a development folder
sudo mkdir /mnt/webconverger
sudo mount -o loop latest.iso /mnt/webconverger

mkdir devfolder
rsync -av /mnt/webconverger/ devfolder/

sudo umount /mnt/webconverger
sudo rm -r /mnt/webconverger

# 3. Change the file in the development folder. 
chmod -R 777 devfolder/

rm devfolder/boot/live.cfg
echo \
"DEFAULT de

label de
    menu label Start
    kernel /live/vmlinuz
    append initrd=/live/initrd.img boot=live skipconfig quiet splash components=gitfs net.ifnames=0 bootfrom=removable locale=de xkb=-layout%20de homepage=https://www.google.de/" \
> devfolder/boot/live.cfg

# 4. Create a new ISO image
mkisofs -o new.iso -l devfolder
rm -r devfolder/
```

The generated ISO does not boot.
I asume the reasons for the problem are, <s>that I had to run the whole script with root privileges and</s>  that I need a more complex `mkisofs` command.

**Does anybody know how to generate a proper ISO image for Webconverger with a shell script? Or is there an alternative method for the whole process? Something like ISO Master but for the command line?**

---

#### Update

I have replaced the code snippets with the actual shell script. So it is easier to test. And here is the command line output (without the wget part):

```
mount: /dev/loop0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
sending incremental file list
./
boot/
boot/boot.bin
boot/boot.cat
boot/live.cfg
boot/syslinux/
boot/syslinux/ldlinux.c32
boot/syslinux/libcom32.c32
boot/syslinux/libutil.c32
boot/syslinux/splash.png
boot/syslinux/syslinux.cfg
boot/syslinux/vesainfo.c32
boot/syslinux/vesamenu.c32
live/
live/initrd.img
live/vmlinuz
live/filesystem.git/
live/filesystem.git/HEAD
live/filesystem.git/config
live/filesystem.git/description
live/filesystem.git/packed-refs
live/filesystem.git/shallow
live/filesystem.git/branches/
live/filesystem.git/hooks/
live/filesystem.git/hooks/applypatch-msg.sample
live/filesystem.git/hooks/commit-msg.sample
live/filesystem.git/hooks/post-update.sample
live/filesystem.git/hooks/pre-applypatch.sample
live/filesystem.git/hooks/pre-commit.sample
live/filesystem.git/hooks/pre-push.sample
live/filesystem.git/hooks/pre-rebase.sample
live/filesystem.git/hooks/pre-receive.sample
live/filesystem.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg.sample
live/filesystem.git/hooks/update.sample
live/filesystem.git/info/
live/filesystem.git/info/exclude
live/filesystem.git/objects/
live/filesystem.git/objects/info/
live/filesystem.git/objects/pack/
live/filesystem.git/objects/pack/pack-1aa978c13266848f4644754d1875dc90ec4bfcdb.idx
live/filesystem.git/objects/pack/pack-1aa978c13266848f4644754d1875dc90ec4bfcdb.pack
live/filesystem.git/refs/
live/filesystem.git/refs/heads/
live/filesystem.git/refs/heads/master
live/filesystem.git/refs/remotes/
live/filesystem.git/refs/remotes/origin/
live/filesystem.git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
live/filesystem.git/refs/tags/
live/filesystem.git/refs/tags/initial-revision

sent 598,528,659 bytes  received 726 bytes  239,411,754.00 bytes/sec
total size is 598,380,033  speedup is 1.00
I: -input-charset not specified, using utf-8 (detected in locale settings)
  1.71% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:54 2018
  3.42% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:54 2018
  5.13% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:13:13 2018
  6.84% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:13:08 2018
  8.55% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:13:05 2018
 10.26% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:13:03 2018
 11.97% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:13:02 2018
 13.68% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:13:01 2018
 15.39% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:13:00 2018
 17.10% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:59 2018
 18.81% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:59 2018
 20.52% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:58 2018
 22.23% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:58 2018
 23.94% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:58 2018
 25.65% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:57 2018
 27.36% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:57 2018
 29.07% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:57 2018
 30.78% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:57 2018
 32.49% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:57 2018
 34.20% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:56 2018
 35.91% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:56 2018
 37.62% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:56 2018
 39.33% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:56 2018
 41.04% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:56 2018
 42.75% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:56 2018
 44.46% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:56 2018
 46.17% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:56 2018
 47.88% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:56 2018
 49.59% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:56 2018
 51.30% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:55 2018
 53.02% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:55 2018
 54.72% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:55 2018
 56.44% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:55 2018
 58.14% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:55 2018
 59.86% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:55 2018
 61.56% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:55 2018
 63.28% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:55 2018
 64.98% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:55 2018
 66.70% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:55 2018
 68.40% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:55 2018
 70.12% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:55 2018
 71.82% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:55 2018
 73.54% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:55 2018
 75.24% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:55 2018
 76.96% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:55 2018
 78.66% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:55 2018
 80.38% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:55 2018
 82.08% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:55 2018
 83.80% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:55 2018
 85.50% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:55 2018
 87.22% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:55 2018
 88.92% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:55 2018
 90.64% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:55 2018
 92.34% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:55 2018
 94.06% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:55 2018
 95.76% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:55 2018
 97.48% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:55 2018
 99.18% done, estimate finish Tue Jul 10 20:12:55 2018
Total translation table size: 0
Total rockridge attributes bytes: 0
Total directory bytes: 30720
Path table size(bytes): 222
Max brk space used 2b000
292387 extents written (571 MB)
```

And this what I get in VirtualBox:
[Click here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUcZi.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to generate an **El Torito** bootable CD with an **MBR** in its first bytes.

[`mkisofs(8)`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkisofs) needs some special options to create an "El Torito" bootable CD:

```
mkisofs -r -J -l -V "Webconverger" -b boot/boot.bin -c boot/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -o new.iso devfolder
```

Explaination:

```
-r -J: Enable Joliet and Rock Ridge meta data.
-l: Allow long filenames.
-V: Set volume ID. Optional.
-b: Specify the "El Torito" boot image.
-c: Specify the "El Torito" boot catalog.
-no-emul-boot: Specify that this is an "El Torito" bootable CD.
-boot-load-size: number of 512 bytes sector to load (4 is what usually works)
-boot-info-table: modify the original boot image appending the Boot Info Table
```

Then, if you want to be able to just *dd* the file on a USB drive you will need to write an MBR onto the ISO:

```
isohybrid new.iso
```

Comment: Thank you! This works like a charm. I still get `I: -input-charset not specified, using utf-8 (detected in locale settings)` and I do not exactly know what it means.

Comment: It means that it is interpreting input file names as they were UTF-8 encoded. This is probably a safe choice, unless you have reasons to believe that the file names are in another encoding.

Answer (score 2):

## So the full answer to the question is:

```
#!/bin/bash
# 1. Download the ISO
wget https://build.webconverger.com/latest.iso

# 2. Mount the ISO and create a development folder
sudo mkdir /mnt/webconverger
sudo mount -o loop latest.iso /mnt/webconverger

mkdir devfolder
rsync -av /mnt/webconverger/ devfolder/

sudo umount /mnt/webconverger
sudo rm -r /mnt/webconverger

# 3. Change the file in the development folder. 
echo \
"DEFAULT de

label de
    menu label Start
    kernel /live/vmlinuz
    append initrd=/live/initrd.img boot=live skipconfig quiet splash components=gitfs net.ifnames=0 bootfrom=removable locale=de xkb=-layout%20de homepage=https://duckduckgo.com nobrand" \
| sudo tee devfolder/boot/live.cfg

# 4. Create a new ISO image
sudo mkisofs -r -J -l -V "Webconverger" -b boot/boot.bin -c boot/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -o new.iso devfolder
sudo isohybrid new.iso
sudo rm -r devfolder/
```

For some reason dd did not work for Webconverger images. Even the with the untouched `latest.iso` it was not possible to create a bootable USB flash drive. So I used [Win32DiskImager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/files/latest/download).